# Why $\sin$ and $\cos$ shows up under this recurrence dynamical system?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, trigonometry, continuity, recurrence-relations, dynamical-systems

I love experimenting with math in Python and have found interesting behaviour which I would like to understand !

---

Why $\sin$ and $\cos$ shows up under this recurrence dynamical system ?
Is there some way to develop discrete equation into continuous solution ?

---

Idea :

$$
y_{n+1} = y_{n} + v_{n}
\\
y_0 = 1
$$

$$
v_{n+1} = v_{n} - y_{n} h
\\
v_{0} = 0
$$

$$
x_{n} = n h
$$

Let :

$$
h^{+} \to 0
$$

Observations :

$$
y_{n} = \cos(x_{n} \sqrt{h})
\\
v_{n} = - \sqrt{h} \sin(x_{n} \sqrt{h})
$$

Plot of $(x_{n}, y_{n})$ and $(x_{n}, v_{n})$ :

[image]

Comment: "Developing discrete equations into continuous solutions" brings us into differential equations. In this case you have $y''=-y$ whose solutions are indeed trigonometric functions.

Comment: "*Why $\sin$ and $\cos$ shows up*" $\;-\;$ If you eliminate $v_n$ between the relations you get the recurrence $y_{n+2}-(2-h)y_{n+1}+y_n=0$. The characteristic polynomial has complex conjugate roots for $h \in (0,4)$, and $y_n$ is proportional to the real part of the $n^{th}$ power of one of those roots, so it follows a $\cos$ curve.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is the explicit Euler method applied to the circle system $\dot y=v$, $\dot v=-y$. With the given initial values it has the solution $y=\cos(x)$, $v=-\sin(x)$.

The numerical method, if executed over a larger number of $2\pi$ periods, will show that the amplitude grows like $(1+h^2)^{n/2}\approx e^{ht/2}$.

---

If the $h$ missing in the first equation is by intention, then using $(y_n, v_n/\sqrt{h})$ as state vector re-establishes the Euler method, this time with step size $\sqrt{h}$ and thus $n\sqrt{h}=x_n/\sqrt{h}$ as the argument of the trigonometric functions.